# Java error getting the bytes of a string to do an XOR check

Tags: java, android, arrays, byte

Hi I am currently trying to use get the Bytes on a string 1 and 2 so I can do an XOR check with string 1 and  modulus of string2 length but I keep coming up with and error "String cannot be converted to bytes" This java code actually came from a decompiled apk and the dex files converted to jar then  viewed from jd-gui. So I am wondering if there was a loss of logic code in the conversion
        =================================================

```
   public class A {
     //initializing
      public static String a(String paramString1, String paramString2)
      {
        //declaring string 1 and 2


        paramString1 = "i]\rD\004\025\027\004_~\002\006`HZ@UBY\\Ku\002O2\003_MQB\020\007G~\004Q";
        paramString2 = "prodkey";


       //getting the byte of string 1 and 2 


        paramString1 = paramString1.getBytes();
        paramString2 = paramString2.getBytes();

       //XOR check  while iterating through paramstring1 byte array


        int[] arrayOfByte = new int[paramString1.length];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < paramString1.length)
        {
         arrayOfByte[i] = ((byte)(paramString1[i] ^ paramString2[(i % paramString2.length)]));
        i += 1;
        }


   //after this I should be able to see string arrayofByte in this format 
    // "1227a5aa-ce82-4da8-hFba6-c4hFe80hFba720"
        return new String(arrayOfByte);



       }

    }
    ====================================
   I also  tried  converting the  code to python but the byte() function 
   just converts it to utf-8  b'string'
```

Comment: `paramString1 = paramString1.getBytes();` is a type error. You cannot assign a byte array to a variable of type `String`. Also, are you sure that what you are trying to do here is legal in your country?

Comment: i do not know what you mean by questioning the legality of what I am doing this code is from a learning lab online that I paid for.     I am trying to iterate each character  of the string in paramstring1  turn it to a byte then store it in an array after that  i will  XOR with paramstring2.length

Comment: Sorry, but decompiled APK and uncovering some obfuscated string sounded like braking some protection mechanism.

Comment: no worries!  yeah I do sound a bit shady btw my work is application security, Im just trying to earn a badge in a lab online since im a junior.